# Is it possible to subtract the number of a particular class from the page count?

Tags: vue.js

I'm very new to Vue and looking for some help. I would like to perform a calculation where a number of a particular class name (showClosed) can be subtracted from the results count. Is this even possible?

I get how many records are returned using this code below

```
resultCount() {
      return Object.keys(this.results).length;
    },
```

This returns all records including the ones which are 'hidden' using CSS.

The problem I have is I want the 'count' to change depending on whether the expired items are displayed or not.  The hidden items all have a class of 'hidden' so I wondered if I could subtract the items with the class hidden from the overall count. I'm sure there is a better way, I just don't know what it is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello, It's possible ofc but can you actually also put an example of what do you have in `this.results` object? `Object.values(this.results).reduce((acc, child) => { // some conditions return acc + 1/0 according to condition }, 0)`. Maybe you can use a reduce function to calculate. If you need a referance https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will check out the referenced URL

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this, assuming that items that have a deletedAt that is not null or undefined are supposed to be hidden. It's generally easier to work from a data perspective, rather than setting the CSS class first and then trying to get data information from which CSS class is set again:

```
computed: {
  visibleResultsCount() {
    const hiddenItems = this.result.filter(x => x.deletedAt != undefined)  // this callback function is assumed for my case, and should be the same as the one you use to check if you should hide with CSS.
    return Object.keys(this.result).length - Object.keys(hiddenItems).length;
}
```

Of course you could also filter on visible items instead and get the length from that. The main takeaway is to compute with the data itself rather than trying to count elements with a CSS class.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help. I hope you can help a little more. The 'deadline'  is a date. If I add a manual date within data e.g. 1 May 2021. It performs the calculation However, I'm trying to pull the data from an array of many objects. metaG is the name of the field. I hope I am explaining myself clearly enough!

 resultCountClosed() {
      const deadline = this.results.filter((result) => result.metaData.G);
    
      if (Date.now() >= new Date(this.deadline)) {
        return Object.keys(this.results).length - Object.keys(deadline).length;
      }
    },